# GPO Replication Issues on Windows Server

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, gpo

We have around 8 servers they are connected with each other and pingable as well. I wanted to create a Group policy and push to all domain joined laptops. But whenever I create a group policy the sysvol folder of other servers doesn't update they still show old policies folder entries.

My main goal is to create a policy and push to all domain joined laptops.